How to filter a set of rasters based on values in another set of rasters (QGIS)
I have two sets of rasters. Water surface elevation (wse) and percent water (water_frac), measured from satellite. The water surface elevation data is very noisy and contains a lot of data that shouldn't be there. I am trying to filter the wse data by water_frac to filter out all of the data points that are less than a certain percent water, say removing those points less than 20% water.
I tried the following equation (replacing wse and waterfrac with their actual file names):
("water_frac@1" >= 0.2) * "water_frac@1"
This "worked" in that it did not have any errors, but it changed nothing/did not accomplish what I wanted. I'm probably not going about this properly, what should I do?

Your formula is: Where water_frac is more than or equal to 0.2, replace it with water_frac, so nothing is changed. I think you want: ("water_frac@1" >= 0.2) * "wse@1"+ ("water_frac@1" < 0.2) * "water_frac@1". To take the value from wse, where water_frac>=0.2, else take the value from water_frac
